# How WordPress reacts to a lack of memory of the server

Tags: php, database, wpdb

I am a newbie with WordPress and I have a little question. I met an issue this morning ("wpdb class was not found") with WordPress and while debugging I find that my wpbg.php file was empty !

Here comes my question:

**Is it possible that WordPress erase the content of a file because the server has no more memory or I need to search somewhere else to understand where the issue came from ?**

The server hosting the website has no more memory (I am gonna buy more memory) even if to add a little change to the .css ^^

Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Memory (aka "RAM") has little to do with disk space. And in my experience, WP never changes files (except of course cache)

Comment: Aye - core files should never be modified except during an installation update. It's possible (albeit unlikely) that a botched update or installation produced the blank file - but more than likely something external is the cause

Answer (score 0):

Edge cases when there is no system memory can happen, but are very unlikely. It might have been some update process that opened the file but failed to complete writing to it. But the chances for that are somewhere between slim to non-exsitant. Most likely it was something unrelated.

Comment: Do you know if an update (of WordPress) can do something like this ?

I a going to look for something else however, thank you

Comment: I am not sure, but if an update failed I would assume that the site would still be in a maintenance state, hmmm actually the 4.8.2 update might have had a change in that file so maybe it is related

Comment: Ok, it will stay a mystery, I'm waiting for a back up of my serv ^^
Thank for reply :)

Answer (score 0):

The wpdb class is defined in wp-includes/wp-db.php, not in 'wpbg.php' (see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/).

Also: no. Lack of memory will stop the execution of your script, i.e. WordPress, but (most probably) not empty any files.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the hyphen, thanks

I understand thanks for answering :)